# Customizing Quarto Tables in R

Tags: r, datatables, quarto

I am trying to start creating some documents using Quarto in RStudio.
In this moment I am creating tables but it seems untidy. I would like to add some lines between rows but I can not find how to do that. With this code I only create one row at the top and other one at the bottom. Hope you can help me, already thanks.

Here is the code:

```
|                               |        |
|-------------------------------|--------|
| Cantidad de eventos           | `r a0` |
| Monto Apuesta (\$)            | `r a1` |
| Monto Acierto (\$)            | `r a2` |
| Ganancia (\$)                 | `r a3` |
| Repago (%)                    | `r a4` |
| Cantidad de usuarios          | `r a5` |
| Cantidad de apuestas          | `r a6` |
| Cantidad de usuarios (nuevos) | `r a7` |
| Extra 1                       | `r a8` |
| Extra 2                       | `r a9` |
```

Comment: How does your output exactly look like in the moment?

Comment: I would like to send a pic but i do not know how. Thanks to your modification i understood what TarJae was saying. It looks very great now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you get this table. Go to visual mode and table!

```
---
title: "test"
format: html
editor: visual
---
    
## Quarto

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|------|------|------|
| bla  | bal  | bal  |
| blo  | blo  | blo  |
| bli  | bli  | bli  |
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but honestly, i tried to reply your code and i dont get the same table. I am doing something wrong but i dont understand what